# Find the nilpotents in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2-1)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> We have the ring $\displaystyle R=\mathbb{Z}_3[x]/I, \ I=(x^2-1)\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ is a principal ideal. The question is to find the elements $a\in R$ such that $a^n=0_R$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I'm trying to understand the form of the elements in $R$.

Firstly, the elements of $R$ have the form $f(x)+I, \ f(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. By the euclidean division there exist $\pi(x)\in\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ and $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_3$ such that $f(x)=\pi(x)(x^2-1)+(ax+b)$. The elements of the form $ax+b$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}_3$ are the following: 
$$A=\{0,1,2,x,x+1,x+2,2x,2x+1,2x+2\}$$

(Is that a correct approach to examine the form of the elements in $R$?)

We have that $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)=(x+1)(x+2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. If $f(x)^n+I=0+I$ then $f(x)^n\in I\Rightarrow (x+1)(x+2)\mid f(x)^n$. By looking at the polynomials in $A$, this is true if $f(x)=0$. But how can I check what happens to the $n-$th power of the rest of the polynomials?

Secondly, I 'm trying to find the invertible elements of $R$. Now we are looking for elements $f(x)\in A$ such that $\gcd(f(x),x^2-1)=1$. Are these $\{1,2,x,2x\}$? How can I find the inverse of $2x$?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chinese remainder theorem gives you an isomorphism of rings $$\Phi : R \longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3, \; \; [f] \mapsto (f(1),f(-1)),$$ so finding the invertible and nilpotent elements of $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_3$ is enough.

Comment: In order to find nilpotent elements, do we examine when $(a^n,b^n)=(0,0)$?

Comment: @maria886 Yes that's enough

Comment: (1,2) is invertible in $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ so $x+2$ is invertible in $R$ and $(x+2)(x+7)=1$ but: $gcd(x+2,x^2-1)=x+2\not =1$ because $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)=(x+2)(x+1)$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$. Shouldn't $gcd$ be equal to 1?

Comment: $x+2$ gets mapped to $(0,1)$ which is not invertible

Comment: Can't we consider the isomorphism $\Phi(ax+b)=(a,b)$? I don't understand why $f\rightarrow (f(1),f(-1))$ is the only isomorphism we can take.

Comment: @maria886 You have just proved that this is not an isomorphism. $x+2$ is not invertible but its image $(1,2)$ is invertible.

Comment: So, we can't use the isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_3$ in order to find the elements we are looking for and then by adding the coset $I$, make conclusions about $R$, right? We need the isomorphism between $R$ and another ring.